# Run command locally when being connected to remote ssh server

Tags: mac, ssh, terminal

I'm on Mac using Terminal for a SSH connection a Linux server, but I guess this could apply for any OS/client.

If I'm using Terminal on my local machine I can open a file in a GUI application by doing `open [appname] [filename]`.

Is it possible to make it that way when connected to a remote server via ssh as well?

I allready have the remote server mounted as drive, so it's accessible via `/Volumes/my_server`, so what I basically want to do is to, when "on the remote server" via ssh, be able to write something like `openlocally [filename]` which sends a command to my local terminal session, or whatever it has to be, that runs `open [appname] [filename]` locally.

Comment: why don't you just open another terminal window or tab?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a mac to check right now, but the ssh manpage says there is an escaped key combination (~^Z) that sends the ssh client to the background. Did you try it ?

Comment: Ah, didnt know about that one. Thanks! :) If I could create a script that would take one argument, run the ~^Z, run `open [appname] $argument`, and then return with `fg` that would be perfect. But I can't find any way to programatically trigger the suspense. Any ideas?

Comment: @phobia: quite possibly you would still have to ~^Z to run the script on your local computer in the first place.

Comment: I am trying to do the same, did you get any success @OMG_peanuts?